# Using function to change div content on checkbox click not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

Same question more else if() statements causes it to stop working.

I'm building a custom order form for my ad agency where the user selects the items they want from a form checkbox and the subtotal/order summary table below updates accordingly. The client is required to get at least the base spot which is $1125, while the four secondary spots are optional and are $450. If the client decides to get extra[s], then the trafficking cost also goes up ($75 each).

Everything works properly until i get to the highest amount, and then then the table doesn't update properly.

updated fiddle with full problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/joelslevy21/5v8Ltkxf/3/

updated script:

```
                    if ( totalFinal == "3,330" ) {
                        $('#companion').css("display","block");
                        $('#quantityCompanion').text("4");
                        $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$1,800");
                        $('#quantityTrafficking').text("5");
                        $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$375");
                    } else if ( totalFinal == "2,775" ) {
                        $('#companion').css("display","block");
                        $('#quantityCompanion').text("3");
                        $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$1,350");
                        $('#quantityTrafficking').text("4");
                        $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$300");
                    } else if ( totalFinal == "2,250" ) {
                        $('#companion').css("display","block");
                        $('#quantityCompanion').text("2");
                        $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$900");
                        $('#quantityTrafficking').text("3");
                        $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$225");
                    } else if ( totalFinal == "1,725" ) {
                        $('#companion').css("display","block");
                        $('#quantityCompanion').text("1");
                        $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$450");
                        $('#quantityTrafficking').text("2");
                        $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$150");
                    } else {
                        $('#companion').css("display","none");
                        $('#quantityTrafficking').text("1");
                        $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$75");
                    }
```

Comment: Calling `.getElementsByClassName()` over and over again isn't good - why wouldn't you just use `$('.final').each(...)` ?

Comment: [Here's a fixed version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/obskfgov/1/). I don't understand what the problem is, exactly.

Comment: @Pointy I wasn't aware that .getElementsByClassName() isn't the best way to call something by it's class, thanks for the info. Thanks for fixing the fiddle, what was wrong with it out of curiosity?

The problem occurs after adding a spot to the order and you try to remove the spot, the trafficking quantity and subtotal in the order summary doesn't go back down to "1" and "$40" respectively, it stays at "2" and "$80".

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with `.getElementsByClassName()`, but the browser has to work at it so doing it afresh with every iteration of the loop just to get a single element is terribly inefficient. Since you're already using jQuery, you might as well go all-in. All I did was move the JavaScript to the body (jsfiddle setting) and add a "quantity" element to the page because it was missing.

Comment: Why is your `function orderSummary()` inside your `function calculate()` and `while(init = document.getElementsByClassName("final")[i++]) {`?

Comment: @Sean I put the orderSUmmary() function inside the calculate() function so that every time someone checks/un-checks a box, the orderSummary is automatically updated. Is there another/better way of doing this?

Comment: The function declaration (`function orderSummary(){`) does not be inside the function, just the call at the end -> `orderSummary()`.

Comment: For some reason when I add 2 more else if() statements, the code breaks, does anyone have any suggestions?
http://jsfiddle.net/joelslevy21/5v8Ltkxf/3/

Comment: Your jsFiddle does not work because you never loaded jQuery or specified where to load your js code. On the top left of the jsFiddle there are 2 dropdowns. In the first one you need to select your jQuery version. In the second select `No wrap - in <head>`. Then click `update` or `run` again. When I made those changes your fiddle worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Trafficking` is always staying at `2`/`$80`, as you are setting it to that due to your `if`/`else`/`if`/`else` block

```
                if ( totalFinal == "805" ) {
                    $('#companion').css("display","block");
                    $('#quantityTrafficking').text("2");  // Sets to 2 
                    $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$80");  // Sets to $80
                } else {
                    $('#companion').css("display","none");
                    $('#quantityTrafficking').text("1");  // Ignored due to other else
                    $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$40"); // Ignored due to other else
                }
                if ( totalFinal == "1,095" ) {
                    $('#companion').css("display","block");
                    $('#quantityCompanion').text("2");
                    $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$500");
                    $('#quantityTrafficking').text("3");  // Sets to 3
                    $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$120"); // Sets to $120

                } else {
                    $('#quantityTrafficking').text("2"); // Sets to 2, as it overwrites other else
                    $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$80"); // Sets to $80, as it overwrites other else
                    $('#quantityCompanion').text("1");
                    $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$250");
                }
```

What you want is an `if`/`elseif`/`else` block

```
                if ( totalFinal == "1,095" ) {
                    $('#companion').css("display","block");
                    $('#quantityCompanion').text("2");
                    $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$500");
                    $('#quantityTrafficking').text("3");
                    $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$120");
                } else if ( totalFinal == "805" ) {
                    $('#companion').css("display","block");
                    $('#quantityCompanion').text("1");
                    $('#subTotalCompanion').text("$250");
                    $('#quantityTrafficking').text("2");
                    $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$80");
                } else {
                    $('#companion').css("display","none");
                    $('#quantityTrafficking').text("1");
                    $('#subTotalTrafficking').text("$40");
                }
```

Comment: thanks!! worked perfectly. In regards to declaring the orderSummary() function, is it detrimental having it inside the calculate function, or is it more of a best-practice reason? btw, how do you get inline code to show up in comments? I'm a noob.. can't figure it out

Comment: It is just best-practice to not nest function declarations, to make the functions usable outside of the parent function. To write code in the comments wrap the code in backticks `\`` -> `\`$(function() { ... }\``. To include a backtick, escape it -> `\\``